# Filtering Common Values which is not equals to blank using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

Need help on below case to filter Output based on the common Value and store all the common value apart from Blank space in one  tag and remaining in other  tag.

**INPUT PAYLOAD:
===============**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <CustomerRecord>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>XYZ</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
            <customer_number></customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
            <customer_number></customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10024</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10022</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>XYZ</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10023</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10023</customer_number>
        </Customer>
    </CustomerRecord>
```

**Expected OutPut :
====================**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Record>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
        </Customer>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10023</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>XYZ</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10023</customer_number>
        </Customer>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10024</customer_number>
        </Customer>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10022</customer_number>
        </Customer>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>XYZ</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
            <customer_number/>
        </Customer>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
            <customer_number/>
        </Customer>
    </Record>
</Root>
```

**XSLT Transformation added:
============================**

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/CustomerRecord">
        <xsl:variable name="groups">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Customer" group-by="customer_number">
                <group size="{count(current-group())}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Root>
            <xsl:for-each select="$groups/group[@size > 1]">
                <Record>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Customer"/>
                </Record>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <Record>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$groups/group[@size = 1]/Customer"/>
            </Record>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Need all the common `<customer_number>` field values in one apart from blank values in `<Record>` and remaining in other `<Record>` tags.**

Answer (score 0):

***-- edited in response to clarification of requirements --***

As noted in comments below, this is a rather trivial exercise and I don't see why you could not do this on your own:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/CustomerRecord">
    <Root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Customer" group-by="customer_number">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <Record>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </Record>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <Record>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                        </Record>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks a lot for the solution. The above given solution is working when only one common <customer_number> value is present in the Input Payload, But if another Common <customer_number> comes under Input payload then it is getting added in the same first common target <Record> field, instead it should create another <Record> tag, and other <customer_number> Field values should be in the seperate <Record> tag.
I have edited the initial Expected output xml content.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you simply want to group `Customer` by `customer_number`. A rather trivial exercise.

Comment: Yes ..... Also if blank value present in the customer_number for more records then they should pe kept seperatly as shown in the Expected Output Payload

Comment: Ok, so you should be able to figure out this for yourself.

Comment: Can you please help for this case ?

Comment: I get the feeling you are not using the help you get here correctly; you should be learning from these solutions, not just copy them as they are given to you.

Comment: I am trying, but not very much familiar with XSLT. also I am not copy pasting the case as I need to make changes at many end point and also I am converting same details using groovy as well.
So wanted help as we have a deadline.

Comment: Is your question answered?